# Cache Hit or Miss?

Tags: caching, assembly, cpu-architecture

Can ANYONE solve where these instructions will be hit or miss in cache?

Assembly in Nios-II (http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii5v1.pdf)

Size: 128 Byte.
Length: 16 Byte.
Two-way set  Associative.

```
1 movia r8, 0x357B40
2 ldw r10, 0 (r8 ) # 0x357B40
3 ldw r11, 16 (r8 ) # 0x357B50
4. ldw r12, 40 (r8 ) # 0x357B68
5. stw r13, 132 (r8) # 0x357BC4
6. ldw r14, 8 (r8) # 0x357B48
7. stw r15, 135(r8) # 0x357BC7
8. ldw r16, 64 (r8) # 0x357B80
```

Answer (score 0):

The only correct answer to your question is "*No, nobody can determine which of these instructions will cause cache hits or cache misses*".

There are 2 reasons for this. First; it's impossible for any of us to determine what was in the cache before this code executes. Second; it's impossible for any of us to determine if/when any IRQs will occur or rule out the possibility of an IRQ doing something that pushes data out of the cache or fetching something into the cache.

However; if we assume there are no IRQs at all and also assume the cache was empty beforehand; then the answer to your question would be "*Yes, someone can determine which of these instructions will cause cache hits or cache misses*".

Comment: Note: I may have assumed that you're asking people to do your homework for you...

Comment: You would be correct.Very elaborate answer though. Must have been worth your while! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes assuming nothing else is going on (no ISRs, etc) you can determine which of those instructions will result in a cache miss and which a cache hit on an instruction by instruction basis (some of them may require an assumption like there is nothing in the cache when this code starts, the others not).

Not going to do your homework for you.